# unexpected line breaks in python after writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

i have a code that updates CSVs from a server. it gets data using:

```
a = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = a.read().strip()
```

then i append the data to the csv by

```
f = open(filename+".csv", "ab")
f.write(ndata)
f.close()
```

the problem is that randomly, a line in the csv gets written like this (or gets a line break somewhere along the csv):

```
2,,,,,
015-04-21 13:00:00,18,998,50,31,2293
```

instead of its usual form:

```
2015-04-21 13:00:00,6,1007,29,25,2394
2015-04-21 13:00:00,7,1004,47,26,2522
```

i tried printing my data in shell after the program ran, and it would show that the broken csv entry actually appears to be normal.

hope you guys can help me out. thanks.

running python 2.7.9 on win8.1

Comment: Why are you opening a CSV in binary mode?

Comment: I hope you know that `ndata` should be `data` in above code snippet. Maybe it was a typo.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - read in some answers here that CSVs should be opened in binary if in windows. did try opening it just in "a" mode too.

Comment: @ρss - yeah, it's a typo. the csv gets updated to today's date, only problem is that weird line break.

Answer (score 0):

What actions are performed on your "ndata" variable ?

You should use the csv module to manage CSV files : https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Edit after comment :

If you do not want to use the "csv" module I linked to you, instead of

```
a = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = a.read().strip()
ndata = data.split('\n')
f.write('\n'.join(ndata[1:]))
```

you should do this :

```
a = urllib.urlopen(url)
f.writelines(a.readlines()[1:])
```

I don't see any reason explaining your randomly unwanted "\n" if you are sure that your incoming data is correct. Do you manage very long lines ?
I recommand you to use the csv module to read your input : you'll be sure to have a valid CSV content if your input is correct.

Comment: no other operations are done on the data.

after appending, but before i close the file:
'df = pd.read_csv(filename+".csv")
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.to_csv(filename+".csv", index=False)`